# Share this button affects front page menu when blog is promoted to front page

Tags: theming, social-network

I am using the [Share This](http://drupal.org/project/sharethis) module in Drupal 6 to put a button in blog page only, and when I am promoting a blog entry to front page my primary link menu displays with incorrect CSS.

Is there a conflict between the ShareThis CSS and my theme? How can I resolve it?

Comment: There is no way that you will get what you want by asking the question this way. This question will be closed unless you make it more specific and include details about what modules and versions you're using, what you've already tried, and what your problem looks like.

Comment: i am using drupal 6 and i am using sharethis module with css from http://w.sharethis.com/button/css/sharethis.f8aeb821aa52b7af5ae4d3675118594c.css

Comment: Additional helpful information: What theme(s) do you have enabled? Have you changed any code or applied patches? Can you post a link to a screenshot of the problem, and one of how it is supposed to look? Have you tried inspecting the CSS? (command+shift+i in Firefox will display an inspector) What do you see?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. It is rather impossible to say if there is a conflict between your theme, and that module, without seeing the CSS styles your theme is using.